# Looping thru checkbox to determine checkbox id and see if this is checked

Tags: asp.net

I have a requirement to loop through all checkboxes in ASP.Net page and determine the ID of the checkbox and process a logic if this is checked. Any pseudo code will help. Regards - Yagya

Comment: Show us some code. Are these checkboxes in a list? Or randomly placed anywhere on the page?

Comment: using simple javascript or jquery is allowed - or on code behind only ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ControlCollection of the form to loop through

```
foreach (Control ctl in Form.Controls)
{
  if (ctl is CheckBox)
  {
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)ctl;
    // Process chk as you wish
  }
}
```

If you wish to check within any containers (panels etc), write the code in a recursive function like this one

```
  void CheckControls(ControlCollection collection)
  {
    foreach (Control ctl in collection)
    {
      if (ctl is CheckBox)
      {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)ctl;
        //
      }
      if (ctl.Controls.Count > 0)
        CheckControls(ctl.Controls); // Step into the container & check inside
    }
  }
```

Call the CheckControls with the Form's control collection

```
CheckControls(Form.Controls)
```

& it will step into all containers as well

Comment: Hello - Thanks for the comments. I am using master page with contenplaceholder in it. In that case would it work?

Comment: Yes, you can pass on your ContentPlaceHolder's Controls member to the function.